# Website won't scroll with arrow keys in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scroll

Okay, I know this is probably the most simple thing in the world but I can't sort it.

I am working on a site and it won't scroll with the keyboard arrows.

I know it is probably due to a focus but have no clue where.

http://www.hathershaws.eighty3dev.co.uk/

Comment: Its scrolling down with keyboard arrows for me.

Comment: Do you mind me asking which browser?

Comment: I am using Firefox.

Comment: Looks like it is just chrome effected

Comment: @mischiefbec check my answer, there's a problem with one of your plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, it's this script: `smoothscroll.js`, disable it and you will be able to scroll using the arrow keys

Chrome dev tools warning:

> Intervention] Registering mousewheel event as passive due to
>   smoothscroll.js usage. The smoothscroll.js library is buggy, no longer
>   necessary and degrades performance. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5749447073988608

[image]